# Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, codable

Here is my json:

```
[
  {
    "question": "What is the name of your favorite teacher?",
    "id": "Q1.1",
    "created_at": null,
  },
  {
    "question": "What is the name of your favorite singer?",
    "id": "Q1.2",
    "created_at": null,
  },
  {
    "question": "What is the name of your favorite teacher?",
    "id": "Q1.3",
    "created_at": null,
  }
]
```

How can I parse it using Codable? What should my struct?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The root object is an array (`[]`). You have to decode `[Foo].self`, Foo is the struct representing the dictionaries (`{}`)